# SSH Port Forward 22

Tags: ssh, openssh, port-forwarding

I'm trying to set up the following:

At work I want to create a local port that will forward to port 22 on my home server.

ssh -L 56879:home:22 username@home -p 443

right now I'm testing this on my two machines at home, my ubuntu server and the other my iMac.

iMac: 192.168.1.104
ubuntu: 192.168.1.103

iMac -> ssh -p 443 -L 56879:192.168.1.103:22 username@192.168.1.103

in my ~/.ssh/config on my iMac I have port set to 56879.

so when I do git pull remoteserver:/path/to/repo.git on my iMac git will use ssh client on my iMac and use port 56879 since setup in config which should forward to 22 on my ubuntu machine.

I keep getting connection refused? Any ideas?

Comment: looks like i was a bit confused on -L, its <local port>:<local address>:<remote port>

Comment: getting closer to getting my ssh port forward to work. Now getting 'channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed'. Any one know what that means?

Comment: figured out that doing a local forward will function as an incoming forward. i think i'd have to use a proxy command or something equivalent to get my desired result.